# CKEDITOR - Which plugin or settings turns ON/OFF CKEDITOR formatting marks?

Tags: ckeditor

I am looking for settings or plugin which turns ON/OFF the following in text input in CKEDITOR:

[Example Screenshot, formatting marked with Yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVHXS.png)

Example with text:

......................................

H1 Title text

......................................

......................................

p

Lorem Ipsum

Paragraph line 2

Paragraph line 3

......................................

How can I turn on/off, these marks of HTML source formatting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The add-on is called [Show Blocks](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/showblocks)

The relevant configuration option is called `startupOutlineBlocks`

Example: `config.startupOutlineBlocks = false;`